# cv::Mat graystyle conversion

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, computer-vision

I have cv::Mat created from RGB image with 8 bits per component, 4 channels (CV_8UC4). I want to convert it to graystyle Mat and after that store back my graystyle Mat into 4 channel Mat. How can I do that? The folowing code brings me to EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
void myMethod(const Mat& mat) {
      cv::Mat gray;
      cv::cvtColor(mat, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
      gray.copyTo(mat);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to have that function? It doesn't present any new functionality.

Comment: BTW are you sure that you have an RGB image, since OpenCV opens the images with default BGR.

Comment: How does "RGB" and "4 channels" mix? do you have RGBA?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a const reference, if you want to change the data:

```
void toGrayscale(cv::Mat& mat)
{
     cv::Mat gray;
     cv::cvtColor(mat, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
     cv::cvtColor(gray, mat, CV_GRAY2RGB);
}
```

**Edit:** Corrected the answer thanks to Christian Rau input.

Comment: Are you sure `cv::Mat::copyTo` distributes the gray channel into the 4 color channels and doesn't just reallocate `mat` to be a 1-channel matrix, too?

Comment: @ChristianRau: the documentation states that the destination matrix will be reallocated if needed: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#cv-mat-copyto

Comment: Yes but the question is, does it need to be reallocated if the source is 1-channel and the destination 4-channel or is `cv::Mat::copyTo` intelligent enough to distribute the 1 channel of the source image into the 4 channels of the destination.

Comment: Did you read the documentation that I linked to? Quote: "Before copying the data, the method invokes

`m.create(this->size(), this->type);`

so that the destination matrix is reallocated if needed."

Comment: Ah Ok sorry, somehow overead the details. But now you see yourself that your answer won't work for him, since it will indeed turn the destination `mat` into a 1-channel image instead of copying the gray values into the 4-channel image.

Comment: Hehe, you are right! I did not read the question careful enough.

Comment: In fact your answer is nearly correct, you just need to turn the last line into a `cv::cvtColor(gray, mat, CV_GRAY2RGB);`